# Does keyBy partition the DataStream across parallel tasks in Flink (scala)?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, guava, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to apply a ProcessFunction() on an input data stream in Flink, to process each and every incoming element, with a single cache object. My code looks something like this :

```
object myJob extends FlinkJob {
 private val myCache = InMemoryCache()

 private def updateCache(myCache,someValue) : Boolean = {//some code}

 private def getValue(myCache,someKey) : Boolean = {//some code}

 def run(params, executionEnv) : Unit = {
   val myStream = executionEnv.getStream()

   val processedStream = myStream.process(new ProcessFunction {
     def processElement(value,context,collector) : Unit = {
      //Update cache
      //Collect updated event
     }
   }

   processedStream.write()
 }
}
```

When I parallelize this job, I'm assuming that each parallel instance of the job will have it's own cacheObject and hence, a single cache key, could be present, in multiple cacheObjects. However, I'd like there to be a single cache entry for a particular key, that is, all of the records, corresponding to a particular key, must be processed by a single instance and a single cacheObject. Will using keyBy() on myStream, ensure this, that all of the incoming events, with the same key, are processed by a single parallel task/instance of the Flink job and hence, also by a single cacheObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, keyBy guarantees that every event with the same key will be processed by the same instance of an operator. This is essential for high throughput, low-latency stateful stream processing.

This enables flink's state to be local, which makes it easy to work with, and fast. Timers also take advantage of this keyed partitioning.

Using [Flink's keyed state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#working-with-state) would probably work much better than using cache objects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an object I believe you should use a [state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html).

All events with the same key will have access to the same state thus to the same value. Modifying one of those states will not affect the other keyed states.

Comment: Seems helpful. Do you think that the above pattern will result in multiple cache objects and a single key being present in multiple such objects? If yes, then what will be the effect of keyBy operator on the same stream?

Comment: From my point of view yes, it will result in multiple cache objects. Every key will have a different cache object, but I am not an expert on this topic, so I would not want to mislead you. But using a state on a keyed stream will ensure that you will have one distinct value per key.